# SQL Server 2008 Creating Table with date column with specified format

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table

I have to create a table with 3 columns as (dtFrom, dtTo, service_time). 
dtFrom & dtTo is datetime , service_time is int. Now in datetime column I have to save date as 22-Apr-2018. How should I set format in CREATE TABLE query.

I have googled it but didn't found any help.

Below is CREATE TABLE query:

```
create table tbl_previous_policy
(
 dtFrom datetime NOT NULL,
 dtTo datetime NOT NULL,
 service_time int NOT NULL
)
```

Now how should I set the format for datetime columns in above query?

Comment: are you actually saying you searched and were unable to find the syntax of 'create table'? or are you mixing up presentation with representation? A datetime column is binary; how you display that is not related to how you store it. I.E don't attempt to store a date as a formatted string!

Comment: Show us your current CREATE TABLE attempt.

Comment: Sir found CREATE TABLE` syntax but didn't found regarding datetime format in `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: sir updated my question with `create table` query

Comment: Date format depends on few things, like regional settings, language settings, also you could set default date format, check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 ...

Comment: The  point you're missing is, you do not set a format on datetime storage; format is the concern of presentation.

Comment: I feel like upvoting a comment isn't enough, @MitchWheat is bang on the money here. (Display) Formatting is for the presentation layer, never store your formatted data in the data engine; you're asking for trouble. For example the following statement is true `'22-Apr-2018' < '30-Mar-1990'`. Yes, that's right `'22-Apr-2018`' is **before** `'30-Mar-1990'`.

Comment: On a different note, you're using SQL Server 2008, so why aren't you using the `date` and `time` data types? Especially in regards to `service_time`, which you've declared as an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MitchWheat is absolutely correct in his comment.  Date/times are stored in an internal format.

One thing you can do is add a computed column to the table and use that for the correct format.  You can do this as:

```
create table tbl_previous_policy (
    dtFrom datetime NOT NULL,
    dtTo datetime NOT NULL,
    service_time int NOT NULL,
    dtFrom_ddmmmyyyy as ( replace(convert(varchar(11), dtFrom, 106), ' ', '-') ),
    dtTo_ddmmmyyyy as ( replace(convert(varchar(11), dtTo, 106), ' ', '-') )
);
```

You can now use the additional fields when you want to output the date in your preferred format.  You can also manipulate the existing values using the built-in date/time functionality.

Comment: you could do this, but I never would.